# Can't enable AirPlay system-wide, but it works in iTunes 11

Tags: itunes, macos, audio, appletv, airplay

I can enable AirPlay from iTunes to my Apple TV and it works great. In the system-wide audio output devices, the Apple TV is also listed. When I click on it to select it, the selection immediately returns to Internal Speakers. Console notes that I have selected the AirPlay endpoint, but does not give an indication that anything has gone wrong.

OS X 10.9.4
iTunes 11.3.1 (2)

Comment: In my case, the Apple TV is selected, there is a couple of milliseconds of mute when switching, but it continues to play from internal speaker. OS X 10.11.3. It used to work. Restart does not help.